# Fresco java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libnative-imagetranscoder.so" not found - Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android, imageview, fresco

Adding this did not solve my problem
`implementation("com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:3.0.0")`

but this solved my problem with Android Studio with Java in gradle  dependencies

```
implementation("com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder") {
        version {
            strictly("2.6.0")
        }
    }
```

Did not now I should be including this lib

```
com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder
```

Comment: Can you give general explanation on what you are trying to do~

Comment: The aar file of 2.6.0 contains `libnative-imagetranscoder.so` for all 4 major ABI and has a size of 685KB, version 3.0 does not contain any .so files and has a size of 5KB (and the dependencies have not changed). May be v3.0 is a defect release?

Answer (score 0):

We can use like

```
implementation("com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.6.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in Fresco v3.1.3 released on Oct 25, 2023.

Please try using that instead: `implementation("com.facebook.fresco:fresco:3.1.3")`